# how to "update" the time in the program in java

Tags: java

Write   the method  delay.  To  design  it, we  use a   Java    Library System.currentTimeMillis()  method
to  read    the system’s    time    value.  The system  time    is  the integer number  of  milliseconds    that
have    elapsed since   12:00 a.m. January  1,  1970.   This    method  returns a   long type.      Remember
that    long is just    a   larger  integer.        Here's  a   pseudocode description  of  the delay   method  that    you 
should  write:

ending  time    =   system  time    +   amount  to  delay
while   system time is  less    than    ending  time
update  the system  time

After   completing  your    delay method,   visually    check it    by inserting    a   call    to  it  with    an  argument of 
400 after   each    of  the method  calls   in  the no-arg Row constructor. This    should  provide a 0.4
second delay    between each    of  your    method  calls,  thus allowing   you to  see the changes to  the 
display in  slower  sequence.

So I got:

```
public void delay(long waitAmountMillis) {
    double amountOfDelay = 400;
    double endingTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + amountOfDelay;
    while (System.currentTimeMillis() > endingTime) {
        System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
}
```

it failed the test saying 0.0 is what comes out, not 400.0
so im unsure how to make the program update the time.

Comment: Why are you taking a parameter if you're not using it?

Comment: `while ( System.currentTimeMillis() > endingTime)` is wrong (according to your pseudocode). it should be `<`

Comment: What do you mean 'failed the test saying 0.0 is what comes out'? Would you mind including test as well?

Comment: I am unable to provide because it needs to be a picture. edit: expected: <400.0> but was: <7.0> @TomaszPlaskota

Comment: @UnholySheep ah, so I fixed that but it still doesnt print the correct thing so i am unsure what to do because I tried 0.4 and 400

Comment: What doesn't print the correct "thing"? In your code there are no print statements, so it's really unclear what you are talking about. (On other notes, why are you using `double` types?  There is nothing in that code that would require it. You should probably use `long` instead, as per your instructions)

Comment: @UnholySheep I cant use long because for 0.4 is a double and the program will not compile with it being long

Comment: What 0.4?? There is no 0.4 in your code.